# Как в JS получить время определенного часового пояса?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Например, киевское время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d=new Date()

time_zone=d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Для смены даты другого пояса надо прибавить минуты часового пояса к минутам даты.

**Обновление**

```
<?php

  date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); // Устанавливаем часовой пояс по Гринвичу

  $time = time(); // Вот это значение отправляем в базу

  $offset = 3; // Допустим, у пользователя смещение относительно Гринвича составляет +3 часа

  $time += 3 * 3600; // Добавляем 3 часа к времени по Гринвичу

  echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time); // Выводим время пользователя, согласно его часовому поясу
?>
```

Comment: Получается, что дату отдельного часового пояса нужно задавать относительно другого ч.п.?

Comment: Да, относительно своего часового пояса.

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит. Нужно вывести время не относительное, а точное для часового пояса. Может, php?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Я же говорю, что не знаю часовое смещение пользователя